# execute all functions beginning or contain "xx" in function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, each

I have a js file with many functions

```
function one(){
//do stuff
}

function two(){
//do stuff
}

function execute_top_one(){
//do stuff
}

function execute_top_two(){
//do stuff
}
```

and I need to create a function that executes, for example, all functions that start with (or contain) "execute_top" in the function name, instead of having to call all the functions manually like this

```
execute_top_one();
execute_top_two();
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Sounds like you are approaching this the wrong way. Why do you need it? Wouldn't it make more sense to have an array with functions that you just loop over and execute all of them? (And possibly an object with several such arrays?)

Comment: Well, you're absolutely right. It would be the most logical thing to do. But I don't have such a level to be able to create it from zero. Any example you can reference me with?

Comment: I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207834/jquery-array-call-function-from-array-in-order) of an array of functions, but what I would like is not to have to write the array (or dynamically generated it's ok), since I can have 4 functions or 120 functions and I don't want to leave any to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do it in a little other way:

```js
const functionStore = {
  one: function() {
    console.log('one')
  },
  two: function() {
    console.log('two')
  },
  execute_top_one: function() {
    console.log('execute_top_one')
  },
  execute_top_two: function() {
    console.log('execute_top_two')
  },
}

const execute_these = "execute_top"

const executeFunctions = (functionStore, filterString) => {
  Object.entries(functionStore).forEach(([fnName, fn]) => {
    if (fnName.indexOf(filterString) !== -1) {
      fn()
    }
  })
}

executeFunctions(functionStore, execute_these)
```

The difference is that you gather your functions into one `object` (I called it `functionStore`, and then create the filtering string & function. As you see from the snippet, filtering an `object`'s keys and values (called `fnName` & `fn` in my snippet) is quite easy - and inside the filtering you can call the functions stored.